# Writing in to dat file clearing old data

Tags: c

I am trying to write to student.dat file.My problem is when i am writing second time my first data is clearing out.please help me

```
student st; 
FILE* fp = fopen("d:\\student.dat", "w");
//fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);   
st.getdata();      
fwrite((char *) &st,sizeof(student),1,fp);
fclose(fp);
printf("\n\nStudent record Has Been Created ");
fflush(stdin);   
getch();
```

Comment: This is clearly explained in [fopen() documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen). You should learn to read documentation, it's a must for a programmer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try append mode:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("d:\\student.dat", "a");
```

`w` mode overwrites file: "Create an empty file for output operations. If a file with the same name already exists, its contents are discarded and the file is treated as a new empty file."

Comment: @anish explain please what is "not working". Overwriting again? Not doing anything? Error?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

```
FILE* fp = fopen("d:\\student.dat", "w");
```

should be

```
FILE* fp = fopen("d:\\student.dat", "a"); // a for append
```